# date format YYYYMMDD is ok when opening the csv file using notepad but not ok when opening the csv file using excel

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I am working on reports and exporting them to csv files. I have to get the dates in the format YYYYMMDD in the csv files. My problem is that when I open the csv file via notepad or block_notes, I am having the exact format, but, when I open it using MS Excel (which is the tool used by default) I am getting the dates in other format DD/MM/YYYY. I need to force it to be be displayed as YYYYMMDD.
How can I do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it stored as a DATE in the table? Example input data would help. I'm afraid I don't understand what your code is doing at all.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is stored as a date. When I export my work to a csv file, this column M_REP_DATE2 is displayed like dd/mm/yyyy automatically. I want to force it to be displayed as YYYYMMDD in the csv file. I hope, I am the idea is clear

Comment: These types of errors occur due to- "Entering a left parenthesis, but missed the closing right parenthesis; or you entered invalid data within the parentheses." Check if, All parentheses are entered in pairs.

Comment: So this is nothing to do with Oracle or SQL at all then? I'm really confused about how any of your question is related to your actual problem. It doesn't seem to be. P.S. It's rude to shout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `M_REP_DATE2` contains your date:

```
SELECT to_char(M_REP_DATE2,"YYYYMMDD")
FROM BM_TRADEATT_REP
```

If that isn't the case, you'll need to provide some details as to what `DT_WSTR` and `M_REP_DATE2` contain.

Comment: your expression works well but not the CSV file, if you try this in oracle for example or aqua studio, it works, but when I export my report containing the field M_REP_DATE2 which is a date field, it is displayed as mm/mm/yyyy

Comment: So you're opening the file in something like Excel, and Excel is automatically formatting the value?  Is that the actual problem here?

Comment: exactly! that's the point. I want to force it to be displayed in that format

Comment: If you want to open java-generated file in Excel, you have two choices:
1) To format cells (columns) manually each time you import CSV in excel
2) To generate XLS(x) file from java using library like POI
From my point of view, 2nd choice is much better

Comment: And, you can use any format you want with the TO_CHAR function, like:

select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy.mm.dd') 
from dual

Comment: If you open the CSV file in notepad, do the dates appear correct?  If so, then this question is an Excel question, and has nothing to do with SQL, Oracle, or CSV in general.  You might be better served by posting a question that asks how to force formatting in Excel.

Comment: I confirm it is displayed in the right format in txt file

Comment: Does adding a space to the end of the date string trick excel?

SELECT to_char(M_REP_DATE2,"YYYYMMDD ")
FROM BM_TRADEATT_REP

Comment: You might find that using the ISO date format of YYYY-MM-DD is the most robust way of transporting dates between systems.